# Retrieved data is not showing up in widget

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a json file hosted on my server which looks like this.

```
{
  "score": "23/6"
}
```

The score is always updating and I want my flutter app to show the realtime score.

Flutter code is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
var json_score;
var json_overs;

class livee extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _liveeState createState() => _liveeState();
}

class _liveeState extends State<livee> {

  final String url = "path_to_my_json";

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this.getJsonData();
  }

  Future<String> getJsonData() async{
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Accept" : "application/json"}
    );


     var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
     json_score = data['score'];


     print(json_score.toString());

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Status bar
    final status = Text(
        "XYZ College",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);


    final score = Container(
      alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
      child: Text(json_score.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50.0,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    );


    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          livestatus,
          score,

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I managed to get the score to my app but it needs to refresh the app to show updated score. How can I make this update the score with an interval?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you're missing here.

The first is that you've made your `var json_score;` and `var json_overs;` essentially global variables which I'm pretty sure wasn't what you meant to do. Unless you have a very specific reason, you generally shouldn't have (non-const) variables outside of classes as they will be shared across all instances of the object.

Furthermore, the way Flutter's stateful widget works is that when you change its state, the flutter engine checks to see whether the object has changed and only rebuilds if it has changed. If the variable isn't in the object, the object won't have changed and therefore won't rebuild.

The other thing you're missing is that every time you change the 'state' of a State object, you should be calling setState(...) and doing the mutation of the state within that function.

I've fixed up your code a little:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Livee extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LiveeState createState() => _LiveeState();
}

class _LiveeState extends State<Livee> {
  final String url = "path_to_my_json";

  var jsonScore;
  var jsonOvers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getJsonData();
  }

  Future<String> getJsonData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    setState(() => jsonScore = data['score']);

    print(jsonScore.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Status bar
    final status =
        Text("XYZ College", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.center);

    final score = Container(
      alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
      child: Text(jsonScore.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    );

    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          livestatus,
          score,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This should work better for you, although I'd personally advise looking into splitting out the score retrieval into a different class and hooking it up to your class with a StreamBuilder rather than how you're doing it, but that is more complicated.

I've a few other remarks not related to the problem but about your code in general.

1. When you post on StackOverflow, it's helpful if you cut down the code to just the problem you're having. This code wasn't that long so it wasn't hard to parse through, but if you had a complicated problem it could be an issue (and the better your question is, the more likely it is to be answered quickly and helpfully =D)
2. I'd recommend reading and following [the dart style guide](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/style) and/or the [flutter style guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo) in your code. Following standards will make your code cleaner and easier for other people to pick up, which will make it easier for you to work with other people (even if your current project is just for you).
3. You seem to have slightly missed some of the base concepts of flutter. They have some actually pretty great tutorials on the [flutter.io website](https://flutter.io/docs) - you'll probably save yourself time and headaches in the long run if you spend a bit of time reading AND writing code alongside it to follow the tutorials as you'll learn lots more that way. [This is the one](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/interactive) in particular that shows how stateful widgets work.